# How to ignore ssl certification check in android because my Webservices is not working after ssl secured?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

After My webservices from server is ssl secured all webservices stop working in android? so i want to know how to ignore ssl certificate check in android.

Comment: what is the error you are getting.?

Comment: Error:Network Error

Comment: when i add https in my url i am getting this error in postman

Comment: but after turning of ssl certification check in postman it worked

Comment: So how to turn off ssl certification check in android

Comment: did you use http://... or https://... on android im frequently switching between those types and never had an issue, maybe its a server side error.

Comment: i am using https

Comment: if this error was server side then it should not work in ios

Comment: can you check in your server url if the lock icon is green or something else